# Error : Dialogflow server in 'us' received request for resources located in 'europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com.'

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to detect an intent with dialogflow, but my dialogflow agent's region is europe-west2 for some reasons. So to specify a location, I use the version v2beta1 of Dialogflow API like described in the documentation. But it doesn't worked and I have the following error `Dialogflow server in 'us' received request for resources located in 'europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com.`

Code :

```js
    const sessionId = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex");
    // Create a new dialogflow session
    const sessionClient = new Dialogflow.SessionsClient(this.dialogFlowConfig)
    const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(this.projectId, "europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com", sessionId);

    // The text query request.
    const dfRequest = {
      session: sessionPath,
      queryInput: {
        event: {
          name: "Welcome",
          languageCode: DialogFlowService.LANGUAGE_CODE
        }
      }
    }

    try {
      const responses = await sessionClient.detectIntent(dfRequest);
      const result = responses[0].queryResult!;
      Logger.debug(`  Query: ${result.queryText}`);
      Logger.debug(`  Response: ${result.fulfillmentText}`);
      if (result.intent) {
        Logger.debug(`  Intent: ${result.intent.displayName}`);
      } else {
        Logger.debug(`  No intent matched.`);
      }
      return result
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the similar issue, but the below config worked to access dialogflow agent's in region europe-west2

- Set the Location as "europe-west2"
- Also need to set the
  SessionsClient's 'apiEndpoint' as
  "europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com"

```
    const sessionClient = new dialogflow.SessionsClient({ apiEndpoint: "europe-west2-dialogflow.googleapis.com" });

    const sessionPath = sessionClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
        projectId,
        "europe-west2",
        sessionId
    );
// The text query request.
    const request = {
        session: sessionPath,
        queryInput: {
            text: {
                text: query,
                languageCode: languageCode,
            },
        },
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `'europe-west2'` as location. More docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/how/region).