# Error passing location to dialogflow.projects.agent.search

Tags: node.js, google-api, dialogflow-es

I want to fetch a user's Dialogflow agents from a specific data region using Nodejs `googleapis` package. When I pass `europe-west2` to `dialogflow.projects.agent.search`, I get the following error:

> 400 - "Dialogflow server in 'us' received request for resources located in 'europe-west2.'"

Do I need to specify the location when I spin up the dialogflow constant with the auth and api version? The only mention of location I found in `v2beta1.d.ts` is for `geoLocation`, which wouldn't apply here. There isn't any mention of an `apiEndpoint` either [like in this question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899334/error-dialogflow-server-in-us-received-request-for-resources-located-in-eur).

Here's my code:

```
const dialogflow = await google.dialogflow({
  auth: oAuth2Client
  version: 'v2beta1'
  // declare location here as well?
})

try {
  const fetchAgentsResponse = await dialogflow.projects.agent.search({
    parent: `projects/-/locations/${location}`
  })
} catch (e) {
  throw e
  // receive the 400 error mentioned above
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the Service Path for SessionsClient to take in the bot's location ahead of the detectIntent call.

```
SessionsClient.servicePath = `${location}-dialogflow.googleapis.com`
```